# How do I configure EclipseLink cache coordination on multiple Liberty instances on IBM Cloud (Bluemix)?

Tags: jpa, ibm-cloud, eclipselink, websphere-liberty

I have an enterprise application running on multiple concurrent Liberty instances on IBM Cloud. I want to use JPA Cache Coordination to ensure that an entity is automatically invalidated in the cache on all other instances, if it is modified on any instance.

EclipseLink offers this capability (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CacheCoordination) - but I haven't been able to locate any information on how to properly configure it on IBM Cloud.

Any hints or examples would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The docs show 3 options - RMI, JMS and JGROUPS. I'd recommend the later 2 options, but you would need to look at IBM docs for how to setup a JMS or JGROUPS for use by EclipseLink.  Someone posted their settings for MQ at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=805994&goto=1417383&

Comment: JGroups doesn't seem to be included in the EclipseLink provided by Liberty: Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-28006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.WAS-v20171031-22b68cc): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: ClassNotFound: [org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.coordination.jgroups.JGroupsTransportManager] specified in [eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol] property.

Comment: see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1069341/ as you may have to pull in the extensions.